# Converting expression involving tranpose of vector to numerical function with lambdify

Tags: python, vector, sympy

I have written a script in python that uses sympy to compute a couple of vector/matrix formulas. However, when I try to convert those to functions that I can evaluate with sympy.lambdify, I get a

> SyntaxError : EOL while scanning string literal

Here's some code with the same error, so that you can see what I mean.

```
import sympy
x = sympy.MatrixSymbol('x',3,1)
f = sympy.lambdify(x, x.T*x)
```

So, the syntax error has to do with the expression "x'.dot(x)" and the conversion of ".T" to '.

How can I work around this to correctly define f from the above lambdify?

Comment: Feel free to report these sorts of things to the SymPy issue tracker. I've opened https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11044 for this.

Comment: @asmeurer Yeah, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been solved in sympy version >= 1.1

Edit:

Example

when u define this
`x = sympy.MatrixSymbol('x',3,1)`
you are creating a matrix,

you can check its indexing and shape using
`print(sympy.Matrix(x))`

Now that you want to multiply Transpose of x to x, you will have to give `x` a matrix of same shape that you have defined before

here try this:

```
from sympy import MatrixSymbol, lambdify, Matrix
x = MatrixSymbol('x', 3, 1)
f = lambdify(x, x.T*x)
a = Matrix([[1], [2], [3]])
print(f(a))
```

you can check this link out to understand lambdify better:
http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see that `f = sympy.lambdify(x, x.T*x)` does not throw an error now. But could you add an example of how one can use this `f`? This would make your answer much more valuable.

Comment: one more thing, I don't know if its relevant to you, still, if you have numpy installed on your system you will get output `14` otherwise `[14]`.

Answer (score 2):

Found a work around, although not the cleanest looking solution... but it works.

Use the implemented_function() method from sympy to define your function. Read full documentation here: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html

Here is the code:

```
import sympy
import numpy as np
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import implemented_function


x = sympy.MatrixSymbol('x',3,1)

f = implemented_function(sympy.Function('f'), lambda x: x.T*x)

lam_f= sympy.lambdify(x, f(x))
```

Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: You'll probably want to define something that actually uses `np.dot` for evaluation.

Comment: Yeah, this just does element-wise multiplication.